# How to control the youtube flash player with c#?

Tags: c#, .net, flash, youtube, youtube-api

My goal is to make a open source YouTube player that can be controlled via global media keys.
The global key issue I got it covered but the communication between the YouTube player and my Windows Forms application just doesn't work for some reason.

So far this is what I have:

```
private AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash player;
player.movie = "http://youtube.googleapis.com/v/9bZkp7q19f0"
...
private void playBtn_Click(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    player.CallFunction("<invoke name=\"playVideo\" returntype=\"xml\"></invoke>");
}
```

Unfortunately this returns:

```
"Error HRESULT E_FAIL has been returned from a call to a COM component."
```

What am I missing? Should I load a different URL?

[The documentation](https://developers.google.com/youtube/articles/youtube_as3_chromeless) states that YouTube player uses **ExternalInterface class** to control it from JavaScript or AS3 so [it should work with c#](http://bojolais.livejournal.com/251383.html).

#### UPDATED:

---

Method used to embed the player: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kg-z8JfOIKw

Also tried to use the [JavaScript-API](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference) in the WebBrowser control but no luck (player just didn't respond to JavaScript commands, tried even to set `WebBrowser.url` to a [working demo](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo), all that I succeeded is to get the `onYouTubePlayerReady()` to fire using the simple [embedded object version](https://developers.google.com/youtube/youtube_player_demo#object-embed-code-header) )

I think there might be some security issues that I'm overseeing, don't know.

#### UPDATE 2:

---

fond solution, see my [answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13260361/how-to-control-the-youtube-flash-player-with-c/16508605?noredirect=1#answer-13604903) below.

Comment: All CPU or 64bit maybe for your application?

Comment: tried both, none worked...
Did you manage to get it to work?

Comment: Nah sorry, just some things I've tried when working with COM. I'm guessing you set it to x86 as well and tried that. Also fire up ProcessMonitor (sysinternals) and track the registry keys it's querying. Might give some pointers.

Comment: I'll try, dough I have no experience in tracking the registry, what should I be looking for?

Comment: This is what I fond :
reg:"HKLM\SOFTWARE\Microsoft\CTF\KnownClasses" RegOpenKey NAME NOT FOUND

Comment: sorry I don't have an actual answer, there will be LOTS of keys scroll by, you will need to look through them, find stuff referring to ShockwaveFlash (denied, notfound etc)  and then follow those up. sorry I can't be more specific, as I just don't know the full answer. It's usually something not registered correctly, or a 32/64bit install mismatch

Answer (score 2, accepted):

After a lot of tries and head-hammering, I've found a solution:

Seems that the `Error HRESULT E_FAIL...` happens when the flash dosen't understand the requested flash call. Also for the youtube external api to work, the [js api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/js_api_reference#GettingStarted) needs to be enabled:

```
player.movie = "http://www.youtube.com/v/VIDEO_ID?version=3&enablejsapi=1"
```

As I said in the question the whole program is open source, so you will find the full code at [bitbucket](http://bit.ly/Tplayer).
 Any advice, suggestions or collaborators are highly appreciated.

### The complete solution:

Here is the complete guide for embedding and interacting with the YouTube player or any other flash object.

After following the [video tutorial](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kg-z8JfOIKw)
, set the flash player's `FlashCall` event to the function that will handle the **flash->c#** interaction (in my example it's `YTplayer_FlashCall` )

#### the generated `InitializeComponent()` should be:

```
...
this.YTplayer = new AxShockwaveFlashObjects.AxShockwaveFlash();
this.YTplayer.Name = "YTplayer";
this.YTplayer.Enabled = true;
this.YTplayer.OcxState = ((System.Windows.Forms.AxHost.State)(resources.GetObject("YTplayer.OcxState")));
this.YTplayer.FlashCall += new AxShockwaveFlashObjects._IShockwaveFlashEvents_FlashCallEventHandler(this.YTplayer_FlashCall);
...
```

#### the FlashCall event handler

```
private void YTplayer_FlashCall(object sender, AxShockwaveFlashObjects._IShockwaveFlashEvents_FlashCallEvent e)
{
    Console.Write("YTplayer_FlashCall: raw: "+e.request.ToString()+"\r\n");
    // message is in xml format so we need to parse it
    XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXml(e.request);
    // get attributes to see which command flash is trying to call
    XmlAttributeCollection attributes = document.FirstChild.Attributes;
    String command = attributes.Item(0).InnerText;
    // get parameters
    XmlNodeList list = document.GetElementsByTagName("arguments");
    List<string> listS = new List<string>();
    foreach (XmlNode l in list){
        listS.Add(l.InnerText);
    }
    Console.Write("YTplayer_FlashCall: \"" + command.ToString() + "(" + string.Join(",", listS) + ")\r\n");
    // Interpret command
    switch (command)
    {
        case "onYouTubePlayerReady": YTready(listS[0]); break;
        case "YTStateChange": YTStateChange(listS[0]); break;
        case "YTError": YTStateError(listS[0]);  break;
        default: Console.Write("YTplayer_FlashCall: (unknownCommand)\r\n"); break;
    }
}
```

this will resolve the **flash->c#** communication

#### calling the flash external functions (c#->flash):

```
private string YTplayer_CallFlash(string ytFunction){
    string flashXMLrequest = "";
    string response="";
    string flashFunction="";
    List<string> flashFunctionArgs = new List<string>();

    Regex func2xml = new Regex(@"([a-z][a-z0-9]*)(\(([^)]*)\))?", RegexOptions.Compiled | RegexOptions.IgnoreCase);
    Match fmatch = func2xml.Match(ytFunction);

    if(fmatch.Captures.Count != 1){
        Console.Write("bad function request string");
        return "";
    }

    flashFunction=fmatch.Groups[1].Value.ToString();
    flashXMLrequest = "<invoke name=\"" + flashFunction + "\" returntype=\"xml\">";
    if (fmatch.Groups[3].Value.Length > 0)
    {
        flashFunctionArgs = pars*emphasized text*eDelimitedString(fmatch.Groups[3].Value);
        if (flashFunctionArgs.Count > 0)
        {
            flashXMLrequest += "<arguments><string>";
            flashXMLrequest += string.Join("</string><string>", flashFunctionArgs);
            flashXMLrequest += "</string></arguments>";
        }
    }
    flashXMLrequest += "</invoke>";

    try
    {
        Console.Write("YTplayer_CallFlash: \"" + flashXMLrequest + "\"\r\n");
        response = YTplayer.CallFunction(flashXMLrequest);                
        Console.Write("YTplayer_CallFlash_response: \"" + response + "\"\r\n");
    }
    catch
    {
        Console.Write("YTplayer_CallFlash: error \"" + flashXMLrequest + "\"\r\n");
    }

    return response;
}

private static List<string> parseDelimitedString (string arguments, char delim = ',')
{
    bool inQuotes = false;
    bool inNonQuotes = false;
    int whiteSpaceCount = 0;

    List<string> strings = new List<string>();

    StringBuilder sb = new StringBuilder();
    foreach (char c in arguments)
    {
        if (c == '\'' || c == '"')
        {
            if (!inQuotes)
                inQuotes = true;
            else
                inQuotes = false;

            whiteSpaceCount = 0;
        }else if (c == delim)
        {
            if (!inQuotes)
            {
                if (whiteSpaceCount > 0 && inQuotes)
                {
                    sb.Remove(sb.Length - whiteSpaceCount, whiteSpaceCount);
                    inNonQuotes = false;
                }
                strings.Add(sb.Replace("'", string.Empty).Replace("\"", string.Empty).ToString());
                sb.Remove(0, sb.Length);                       
            }
            else
            {
                sb.Append(c);
            }
            whiteSpaceCount = 0;
        }
        else if (char.IsWhiteSpace(c))
        {                    
            if (inNonQuotes || inQuotes)
            {
                sb.Append(c);
                whiteSpaceCount++;
            }
        }
        else
        {
            if (!inQuotes) inNonQuotes = true;
            sb.Append(c);
            whiteSpaceCount = 0;
        }
    }
    strings.Add(sb.Replace("'", string.Empty).Replace("\"", string.Empty).ToString());


    return strings;
}
```

#### adding Youtube event handlers:

```
private void YTready(string playerID)
{
    YTState = true;
    //start eventHandlers
    YTplayer_CallFlash("addEventListener(\"onStateChange\",\"YTStateChange\")");
    YTplayer_CallFlash("addEventListener(\"onError\",\"YTError\")");
}
private void YTStateChange(string YTplayState)
{
    switch (int.Parse(YTplayState))
    {
        case -1: playState = false; break; //not started yet
        case 1: playState = true; break; //playing
        case 2: playState = false; break; //paused
        //case 3: ; break; //buffering
        case 0: playState = false; if (!loopFile) mediaNext(); else YTplayer_CallFlash("seekTo(0)"); break; //ended
    }
}
private void YTStateError(string error)
{
    Console.Write("YTplayer_error: "+error+"\r\n");
}
```

#### usage ex:

```
YTplayer_CallFlash("playVideo()");
YTplayer_CallFlash("pauseVideo()");
YTplayer_CallFlash("loadVideoById(KuNQgln6TL0)");
string currentVideoId = YTplayer_CallFlash("getPlaylist()");
string currentDuration = YTplayer_CallFlash("getDuration()");
```

The functions `YTplayer_CallFlash`, `YTplayer_FlashCall` should work for any **flash-C#** communication with minor adjustments like the `YTplayer_CallFlash`'s switch (command).

Comment: Glad you found a solution; did my post help at all?

Comment: Unfortunately, I already knew that information from online research before the time of the answer and it wasn't specific to my problem. 
see section: "Answer the question" from [the stackoverflow answering guide](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/how-to-answer)

Comment: You wrote `parceDelimitedString` instead of `parseDelimitedString`

Comment: I receive Error HRESULT E_FAIL... although I have enabled enablejsapi. It seems to be that YouTube won't support the Flash anymore. :(.

Comment: Don't know, I haven't tested it in 4 years and Google seems to have deprecated the flash+jsapi, you should check if it works in the browser.

Answer (score 4):

It sounds like your trying to use Adobe Flash as your interface; then pass certain variables back into C#.

An example would be this:

In Flash; create a button... Actionscript:

```
on (press) {
    fscommand("Yo","dude");
}
```

Then Visual Studio you just need to add the COM object reference: Shockwave Flash Object

Then set the embed to true;

Then inside Visual Studio you should be able to go to Properties; find fscommand. The fscommand will allow you to physically connect the value from the Flash movie.

```
AxShockwaveFlashObjects._IShockwaveFlashEvents_FSCommandEvent
```

That collects; then just use `e.command` and `e.arg` for example to have the collected item do something.

Then add this to the EventHandler;

```
lbl_Result.Text="The "+e.args.ToString()+" "+e.command.ToString()+" was clicked";
```

And boom it's transmitting it's data from Flash into Visual Studio. No need for any crazy difficult sockets.

On a side note; if you have Flash inside Visual Studio the key is to ensure it's "embed is set to true." That will hold all the path references within the Flash Object; to avoid any miscalling to incorrect paths.

I'm not sure if that is the answer your seeking; or answers your question. But without more details on your goal / error. I can't assist you.

Hope this helps. The first portion should actually show you the best way to embed your Shockwave into Visual Studio.

Make sure you add the correct reference:

1. Inside your project open **'Solution Explorer'**
2. Right-Click to **'Add Reference'**
3. Go to **'COM Object'**

Find Proper object;

```
COM Objects:
Shockwave ActiveX
Flash Accessibility
Flash Broker
Shockwave Flash
```

Hope that helps.

It sounds like you aren't embedding it correctly; so you can make the call to it.  If I'm slightly mistaken; or is this what you meant:

If your having difficulty Ryk had a post awhile back; with a method to embed YouTube videos:

```
<% MyYoutubeUtils.ShowEmebddedVideo("<object width="425" height="344"><param name="movie" value="http://www.youtube.com/v/gtNlQodFMi8&hl=en&fs=1"></param><param name="allowFullScreen" value="true"></param><embed src="http://www.youtube.com/v/gtNlQodFMi8&hl=en&fs=1" type="application/x-shockwave-flash" allowfullscreen="true" width="425" height="344"></embed></object>") %>
```

Or...

```
public static string ShowEmbeddedVideo(string youtubeObject)
{
    var xdoc = XDocument.Parse(youtubeObject);
    var returnObject = string.Format("<object type=\"{0}\" data=\{1}\"><param name=\"movie\" value=\"{1}\" />",
        xdoc.Root.Element("embed").Attribute("type").Value,
        xdoc.Root.Element("embed").Attribute("src").Value);
    return returnObject;
}
```

Which you can find the thread here: [`https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547101/purify-embedding-youtube-videos-method-in-c-sharp`](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2547101/purify-embedding-youtube-videos-method-in-c-sharp)

I do apologize if my post appears fragmented; but I couldn't tell if it was the reference, the variable, the method, or embed that was causing you difficulties.  Truly hope this helps; or give me more details and I'll tweak my response accordingly.

---

C# to ActionScript Communication:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.addCallback("loadAndPlayVideo", null, loadAndPlayVideo);
function loadAndPlayVideo(uri:String):void
{
       videoPlayer.contentPath = uri;
}
```

Then in C#; add an instance of the ActiveX control and add the content into a Constructor.

```
private AxShockwaveFlash flashPlayer;
public FLVPlayer ()
{

      // Add Error Handling; to condense I left out.
      flashPlayer.LoadMovie(0, Application.StartupPath + "\\player.swf");
}

fileDialog = new OpenFileDialog();
fileDialog.Filter = "*.flv|*.flv";
fileDialog.Title = "Select a Flash Video File...";
fileDialog.Multiselect = false;
fileDialog.RestoreDirectory = true;

if (fileDialog.ShowDialog() == DialogResult.OK)
{
     flashPlayer.CallFunction("<invoke" + " name=\"loadAndPlayVideo\" returntype=\"xml">       <arguements><string>" + fileDialog.FileName + "</string></arguements></invoke>");
}
```

ActionScript Communication to C#:

```
import flash.external.ExternalInterface;
ExternalInterface.call("ResizePlayer", videoPlayer.metadata.width, videoPlayer.metadata.height);

flashPlayer.FlashCall += new _IShockwaveFlashEvents_FlashCallEventHandler(flashPlayer_FlashCall);
```

Then the XML should appear:

```
<invoke name="ResizePlayer" returntype="xml">
     <arguements>
            <number> 320 </number>
            <number> 240 </number>
     </arguments>
</invoke>
```

Then parse the XML in the event handler and invoke the C# function locally.

```
 XmlDocument document = new XmlDocument();
    document.LoadXML(e.request);
    XmlNodeList list = document.GetElementsByTagName("arguements");
    ResizePlayer(Convert.ToInt32(list[0].FirstChild.InnerText),   Convert.ToInt32(list[0].ChildNodes[1].InnerText));
```

Now they are both passing data back and forth.  That is a basic example; but by utilizing the ActionScript Communication you shouldn't have any issues utilizing the native API.

Hope that is more helpful. You can expand on that idea by a utility class for reuse.  Obviously the above code has some limitations; but hopefully it points you in the right direction.  Was that direction you were attempting to go?  Or did I still miss the point?

---

Create a new Flash Movie; in ActionScript 3.  Then on the initial first frame; apply the below:

```
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");
var my_player:Object;
var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();

my_loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"))
my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);

function onLoaderInit(e:Event):void{
addChild(my_loader);
my_player = my_loader.content;
my_player.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady); 
} 

function onPlayerReady(e:Event):void{
my_player.setSize(640,360);
my_player.loadVideoById("_OBlgSz8sSM",0);
}
```

So what exactly is that script doing?  It is utilizing the native API and using ActionScript Communication.  So below I'll break down each line.

```
Security.allowDomain("www.youtube.com");
```

Without that line YouTube won't interact with the object.

```
var my_player:Object;
```

You can't just load a movie into the movie; so we will create a *variable Object*. You have to load a special .swf that will contain access to those codes. The below; does just that.  So you can access the API.

```
var my_loader:Loader = new Loader();
my_loader.load(new URLRequest("http://www.youtube.com/apiplayer?version=3"));
```

We now reference the Google API per their documentation.

```
my_loader.contentLoaderInfo.addEventListener(Event.INIT, onLoaderInit);
```

But in order to actually work with our object; we need to wait for it to be fully initialized. So the **Event Listener** will wait; so we know when we can pass commands to it.

The `onLoaderInit` function will be triggered upon initialization. Then it's first task will be `my_loader` to display the list so that the video appears.

The `addChild(my_loader);` is what will load one; the `my_player = my_loader.content;` will store a reference for easy access to the object.

Though it has been initialized; you have to wait even further... You use `my_player.addEventListener("onReady", onPlayerReady);` to wait and listen for those custom events. Which will allow a later function to handle.

Now the player is ready for basic configuration;

```
function onPlayerReady(e:Event):void{
my_player.setSize(640,360);
}
```

The above function starts very basic manipulation. Then the last line `my_player.loadVideoById("_OBlgSz8sSM",0);` is referencing the particular video.

Then on your stage; you could create two buttons and apply:

```
play_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, playVid); 
function playVid(e:MouseEvent):void { 
my_player.playVideo(); 
} 
pause_btn.addEventListener(MouseEvent.CLICK, pauseVid); 
function pauseVid(e:MouseEvent):void { 
my_player.pauseVideo();
}
```

Which would give you a play and pause functionality. Some additional items you could use our:

```
loadVideoById() 
cueVideoById() 
playVideo() 
pauseVideo() 
stopVideo() 
mute()
unMute()
```

Keep in mind those can't be used or called until it has been fully initialized.  But using that; with the earlier method should allow you to layout the goal and actually pass variables between the two for manipulation.

Hopefully that helps.

Comment: embedding wasn't the problem, youtube video plays, and all is fine but I want to control the player from c#, and there comes the error.
This is where I'm at : [http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kg-z8JfOIKw](http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=kg-z8JfOIKw)

Comment: also it seems that the `fscommand` can be used to send data from the flash to c# but not back. I need a 2 way communication system, so I can send commands to the flash player.
Also I would like to use if possible the original [youtube player api](https://developers.google.com/youtube/flash_api_reference#Playback_controls), as it would be easier to maintain.

Comment: In that case you could use ActionScript Communication File; this will allow you to use the Native API.  But then pass to C# so it can be handled locally. I'll edit my response to reflect what I mean; i'll add to bottom.

Comment: yes that's what I'm attempting, but I think that the YouTube player already has this embedded and it uses it to communicate with JavaScript or other AS3/AS2 scripts, but the flashPlayer.CallFunction gives me an error.

Comment: The way I outlined should work; YouTube actually utilizes a special file which is loaded at run time. Then you just use the Loader Class; which will allow any YouTube video to player.  I'll add to my edited post...

Answer (score 2):

I'd start by making sure that javascript can talk to your flash app.

make sure you have: `allowScriptAccess="sameDomain"` set in the embed (from http://help.adobe.com/en_US/FlashPlatform/reference/actionscript/3/flash/external/ExternalInterface.html#includeExamplesSummary).

you should validate that html->flash works; then C->html; and gradually work up to C->you-tube-component.  you have a lot of potential points of failure between C and the you-tube-component right now and it's hard to address all of them at the same time.

Comment: that's what I'm going for.
html->flash works (in chrome/firefox/ie9 but not in the webBrowser component) so that's why I want to embed via the `AxShockwaveFlash` component. So now I will try to get c->flash and see how it goes. c->youtube failed

Comment: if you can do C->JS and JS->flash it seems like there must be a misunderstanding of the you-tube component.  I'm pretty sure if you couldn't control their flash component from flash someone would have noticed by now :) good luck!

Comment: The WebBrowser's JS doesn't work properly , so webBrowserJS->Flash was no go (issues described in question). Also C#->webBrowserJS->flash was the wrong way to go.
I've managed to get c#->flash to work and will post a complete response soon.

Comment: ah, that's too bad.  my area of expertise is entirely on the flash end of your spectrum so my feedback was mostly to figure out if I could offer any support... sorry I couldn't be more helpful

Comment: don't worry, all feedback was helpful :)

Answer (score 0):

This stumped me for a number of hours.

Just add enable JS to your URL:

http://www.youtube.com/v/9bZkp7q19f0?version=3**&enablejsapi=1**

CallFunction works fine for me now! Also remove unrequired space in the call.

Comment: I know, figured it out, see my answer below :) : "_for the youtube external api to work, the_ `js api` _needs to be enabled_"